# How to execute multiline send command in TCL script?

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL scripting and trying to execute the below command in another application using spawn and send command . But getting the below error :

```
    proc otn_line_alarm {} {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        send "table foreach $globalTable row columnName counterValue {          
            if {$columnName== "LOS"  && $counterValue != "clear"} {return 0} } \r ";
         return 1                                                                    
    }
```

below is the error which i am getting

```
    show otn line alarm 9 
    extra characters after close-quote
        while executing
    "exp_send "table foreach $globalTable row columnName counterValue {
          if {$columnName== "LOS"  && $counterValue != "clear"} {return 0} 
    } \r ";
    r..."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to send the literal string to the spawned command. In that case you can enclose it in braces rather than double quotes. The only problem is that the \r is then also not interpreted. The easiest solution is to send that in a separate command:

```
proc otn_line_alarm {} {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    send {table foreach $globalTable row columnName counterValue {          
        if {$columnName== "LOS"  && $counterValue != "clear"} {return 0}
    }}
    send "\r"
    return 1                                                                    
}
```

If you actually do need some variables to be substituted, I would use the format command:

```
proc otn_line_alarm {} {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    send [format {table foreach %s row columnName counterValue {          
        if {$columnName== "LOS"  && $counterValue != "clear"} {return 0}
    }} $globalTable]
    send "\r"
    return 1                                                                    
}
```

Comment: _Sometimes_ it is best to use `format` with `[list $value]` so that appropriate braces are inserted. It depends on how values are being handled by the other side. In any complex case, I prefer to send a procedure (or other language equivalent) and then a short generated call of it; those are so much easier to get correct!